# How can I combine multiple Mongodb queries into one using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

**Context:**

My database has two collections: "Users" and "Files".

Sample document from "Users" collection:

```
{
  "username":"Adam",
  "email":"adam@gmail.com",
  "IdFilesOwned":[1,3],
}
```

As you can see, Adam currently owns two files on the server. Their ids are 1 and 3.

Sample documents from "Files" collection:

```
{
  "fileId":1,
  "name":"randomPNG.png"
}
{
  "fileId":2,
  "name":"somePDF.pdf"
}
{
  "fileId":3,
  "name":"business.pdf"
}
```

As you can see, I have three documents on my server, each document having an id and some metadata.

Now, Adam wants to see all the files that he owns, and their metadata. The way i would implement this, is:

1.Lookup the array of file ids that Adam owns.

2.Have node.js run through each id (using a for each loop), and query the metadata for each id.

The problem is that nodejs will make multiple queries (1 query per id). This seems very inefficient. So my question is if there is a better way to implement this?

Comment: What driver are you using?  Also, why don't you just store the Files in the Users collection (instead of `IdFilesOwned`, just `FilesOwned`)?

Comment: @c1moore i dont store the files with the users because i want to add the ability to share the files with other users (similar to google drive). Also im using nodejs driver 3.4

Comment: You could use an [MongoDB's aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).  I'll try to type up a better answer, but you can use that to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. Ill check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience using the driver directly, but you should be able to do the equivalent of the following

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "files",
      localField: "IdFilesOwned",
      foreignField: "fileId",
      as: "files"
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the $in operator [find more info here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)
So it will look something like this.

```
db.collection('files').find({ fileId: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } })
```

This is more efficent than lookup for sure. Good luck.